# Disable scrolling when pop up open and menu not showing on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

thanks for looking into my issue

I am creating a website: http://testgod0312.000webhostapp.com/ , all the css are separate by blocks so that it is easier for you to potentially help me (in assets folder).

1. when you go to map and click on a button, a pop up shows up, but you can keep on scrolling. The button is only coded in css (no js), everything in the map.css file - any idea how to disable overflow without resorting to js? if using js, what would you do as there is no function capturing the opening / closing of the box?
2. I have a menu (click top right corner), works fine on laptop but on mobile, it shows only 50% of it. The code is in nav.css; with the responsive at the bottom. Any idea on how to display it all?

thanks in advance!!
fafa

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#1 can't be solved without javascript as long as browsers are not supporting [`css:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility). So the only way is to apply a class or a `style="overflow: none;"` to the body as soon as a popup gets opened and remove it after it was closed. The very same happens already if the menu is opened/closed.

A very small code snippet would be enough:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",
  () => document.body.classList.toggle("popup-open", location.hash.startsWith('#popup'))
);
```

and CSS

```css
body.popup-open {
  overflow: none;
}
```

About #2 inside the nav.css the values applied before the media query (`@media all and (max-width: 767px) {`) cause the issue.

The menu__right changes from `flex` to `none` on small screens. And menu__left still has the right 50% value applied for bigger screens, So adjusting this value inside the media query to 0% solves it.

```css
    .menu__left {
        right: 0%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Hey man massive thank you!!!

#2 worked like a charm

#1 i added the css and the js to the files... but it did not work? am i missing something? Do I need some additional libraries? 

I am also going to be a real pain but there would be a small #3... when I click on the map on London a first time all fine. when I click again it does not work... only does it with London, which is weird as it is my marker four... Maybe because the pop up goes on top of it? any help would be welcome 

thanks again!!!

Comment: Please consider asking a new question with the updated site. Currently there is no listener for the hashchange event defined, the 2nd adjustment isn't implemented either and when i test it in the console directly it works as it is supposed to.

Comment: Hey Christopher, 
thank you for your answer, I am not sure what you mean by asking a new question. You mean creating a new thread? I don't want to saturate the site so I dare to write an additional comment... I updated the site with the css (at the bottom of map file, above the reactive) and added the snippet in the js file (at the bottom). Unfortuately it still does not work. It would be really fantastic if you could help me on point #2 (scrolling not disabled when pop up is active) #3 if I click on london on the map it works, if I click a second time it does not work. Thank you again!!

Comment: The 3rd issue seems to appear when the screen is to wide and you scroll back a bit to far due to the `#map` hash call., it looks like an overlapping causes this. It works fine if the site is at 1000px wide. And for #2 the script works, have you added the css part too? The body has the class "popup-open", when i click on any map item.

Comment: After looking a bit into it, "sep__icon" seems to be placed at the very same spot and blocks the button/link. Make sure the sep__icon is hidden if the menu is not open. - And yes, i meant opening a new thread. The comment section is not meant to ask new/other questions.

Comment: all worked, man you are a star thank you!!